# Safe-keeping and long term storage of MMA SE Questions/Answers

Tags: discussion

I wanted to start out by saying that I love the new MMA SE and I hope the meta is the correct place for this post. The MMA SE is turning out to be great and the community is really helpful and I much prefer the interface to the older listservs and usenet newsgroups. However, listservs are easily backed up by a single (or multiple) dedicated users and served off a website with minimal resources and usenet posts are pretty safe from loss.

I was wondering what the long-term plan for archiving all the great questions and answers on the MMA stackexchange should something happen to the site or SE itself.

Although, in a really long time most of the information will probably be outdated by in the next few years or more it would be definitely nice to make sure all this information doesn't vanish.

Comment: You know about the [Data Dump](http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump)?

Comment: @J.M. why don't you make that into an answer?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: if I find time to expand on it later, I will (unless someone beats me to it).